# Mutually exclusive routing shortcut Ardour 5/6

Tags: daw, signal-routing

First thing I do in a session is bus my tracks like a good boii that earnt his sprinkles. However, this would be so much easier if the connection window allowed me to deselect the route to master when routing to a bus.

Is this possible?

Comment: That sounds like one to ask the developers. I've never used Ardour, but that would sound like an action that should be automatic, or at least work with shift or opt held to make bus-add or bus-exclusive switches.

Comment: @Tetsujin yeh it's not great tbh, disappointing as I had high hopes... from memory this is actually a feature of Harrison Mixbus. Looks like I may give Reaper a whirl and see how that pans out, I hear the usability is much more considered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is to press and hold Ctrl whilst selecting the bus route. This will automatically deselect the Master output for that track or bus.